# Debugging cron PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu, cron

```
<?php

ini_set("display_errors",1);
error_reporting(-1);

set_include_path('root/push');

require_once('../../var/www/includes/database.php');
require_once('pushAPNS.php');

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$departure = (string)date('H:i');
$timeNow = "$departure:00";
class Journey {}

try {
    // Get all UDIDs that need to be sent a notificaiton now
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT udid, bus.registration, vjc.vehicle_journey_reference, bus.line, `to`.operator_short_name AS operator, traveline.getDestinationFromJourney(vjc.vehicle_journey_reference) AS destination
                            FROM push_request
                            JOIN cron ON cron.time = :timeNow
                            JOIN traveline.vehicle_journey_code vjc ON vjc.vehicle_journey_reference = cron.vehicle_journey_reference
                            JOIN bus ON bus.journey = vjc.code
                            JOIN traveline.operator `to` ON `to`.operator_code = bus.operator_code
                            WHERE push_request.vehicle_journey_reference = vjc.vehicle_journey_reference");

    $stmt->execute(array(':timeNow' => $timeNow));
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

// Notify every UDID their journey is now trackable
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $journey = new Journey();
    $journey->operator = $result['operator'];
    $journey->line = $result['line'];
    $journey->departure = $departure;
    $journey->destination = $result['destination'];
    pushAPNS($result['udid'], $journey);
}

// Debugging
$conn->query("INSERT INTO a (`time`) VALUES ('$timeNow')");

?>
```

The above code is executed every minute on the server by cron. The code reaches the last line every time apart from when the query returns a result. I can't seem to see any errors in the PHP error log when the script executes, any ideas how I can debug this to fix my problem?

I should add that if I execute the script manually when results will be returned the script works fine. It's just the cronjob that is not liking the query results

Crontab: * * * * * /usr/bin/php /root/push/sendPushNotifications.php

Comment: What's the actual line on the cronjob itself, are you appending the contents of the cronjob to a file or `dev/null?`, are there multiple get paramaters too? `&one=true&two=true?`

Comment: @MackieeE Sorry should have put that in there, edited the question

Comment: You've configured PHP to *display* errors. It isn't clear whether you've configured cron to email them or something. (PHP will use the default settings for logging.)

Comment: @AlvaroG.Vicario Everything is default configuration, I assumed that displaying errors and turning error reporting on would log these files to my php log

Comment: Can you write on 2nd line `$results = false;` to initiate it. *also* are you sure that when its running from cron it realu goes to the last line without errors? and not echoing any connection errors adn so on?
If you see any error (for require) and so on try to add on 2nd line: `echo getcwd();` try also `var_dump`'ing some variables to see if they are correct and so on.

Comment: @Seti Part of the problem is I can't see any errors from cron, they're not showing at `/var/log/apache2/error.log` when the cron is executed

Comment: They will be in other place... Search yours php.ini file for CLI and then edit it (or just view) to see when the logs would be put. But as this isint apache that executes the php but clean command line interface errors would be in different place.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP there're two major things you can decide to do with error messages and they don't depend on each other:

- To **display** messages you set [display_errors](http://php.net/display_errors)
- To **log** errors you set [log_errors](http://php.net/log_errors)

Your code does nothing about logging, it only makes them get displayed. Since cron runs tasks in the background you won't be there to see the errors.

You can:

- Configure cron to send an email message whenever the scripts generates any output: you do it with e.g. the [MAILTO environment variable](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cron)
- [Redirect script output](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) to a file
- Configure PHP to log errors directly

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

it will also start the other errors... But still - find your command line logs. For me it was in `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` then search for error reporting and turn all to `On` set your `error_log = ./debugged_php_errors.log` or something similar.
Not each error will create the log file in the place its running.